# PSC motor auxiliary winding current at full speed

Tags: current-measurement, capacitance, induction-motor

In articles, e.g. [here](https://www.electrical4u.com/split-capacitor-motor/), I often find this statement:

> In an auxiliary winding, a counter EMF is produced as the speed of the motor increases, and this EMF will limit the current that passes through the auxiliary winding.
> When the motor operates at rated speed, a very small current passes through the auxiliary winding.

The issue is that installation engineers will often measure the auxiliary winding current of a PSC motor with a current clamp type instrument to assess the capacitance of the run capacitor under load by measuring the current.

How can both be correct?

Comment: There's no inconsistency. Perhaps you're reading 'limit' as 'hard limit', rather than 'tends to reduce'.